# pass variable from nodejs mongodb to do calculation in other js file an later export that value to the same app.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I need to pass variable from a specific Id from mondodb database to a `calculation.js` and do some calculation and pass that result again to `app.js` file to be render.

The variables that i want to use in `calculation.js` are

```
        var cash = foundAccount.cash;
        var expenses = foundAccount.expenses;
```

`calculation.js` file sample:

```
var calc = cash - expenses;
```

And then export the value of "`calc`" to `app.js` and `res.render`.

```
app.get("/account/:id/balance", function(req, res){
    //find the account with provided ID
    account.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundAccount){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
    //render balance template with that account
            var cash = foundAccount.cash;
            var expenses = foundAccount.expenses;
            res.render("balance", {account: foundAccount, calc: calc});
        }
    });
```

Thanks for any help.

Regards

Alan

Answer (score 0):

`Calc` can be a function in `calculation.js`, e.g.:

```
function calc(cash, expenses) {
  return cash - expenses
}

export default calc;
```

Then you can import the function into your `app.js` file, e.g.:

```
import calc from './calculation';
```

Then call:

```
res.render("balance", {account: foundAccount, calc: calc(foundAccount.cash, foundAccount.expenses)});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.I have  NaN from calc now. any idea?

Comment: if `calc` returns `NaN` one or both the input variables are `undefined` at function call. Check those values

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not using ES6.

You can import the `calc` function from `calculation.js` on top of the routing file here:

```
var calculations = require('/path/to/calculations');

app.get("/account/:id/balance", function(req, res){
//find the account with provided ID
account.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundAccount){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    } else {
//render balance template with that account
        var calc = calculations.calc(foundAccount); //You call the imported function
        res.render("balance", {account: foundAccount,  calc});
    }
});
```

You have to export this function in `calculation.js` :

```
  class Calculations {
     calc(account) {
        var cash     = account.cash; 
        var expenses = account.expenses;
        var calc    =  // do your calculations
        return calc;
     }
  }
  module.exports = Calculations;
```

[EDIT] Since you mentioned, you use es6, so you should start using `let`, `const` instead of `var`, you can read more about the benefits here.
Now the code should be like:

```
import {calc} from '/path/to/calculations';

 app.get("/account/:id/balance", function(req, res){
 //find the account with provided ID
 account.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundAccount){
     if(err){
    console.log(err);
     } else {
 //render balance template with that account
         const calc = calc(foundAccount); // You call the imported function
         res.render("balance", {account: foundAccount, calc});
     }
 });
```

And in `calculations.js` :

```
export const calc = (account) => {
    const cash     = account.cash; 
    const expenses = account.expenses;
    const calc     =  // do your calculations
    return calc;
};
```

Comment: I am using ES6. and express